# CMake - Specifying Linker / Linker Flags during Cross-Compile

Tags: c++, c, cmake, cross-compiling

I am in the process of converting out previous build system (Makefiles) to CMake. I am trying to specify the Linker and Linker Flags for CMake and am not sure if I am using the correct syntax/variables. I have included my original Makefile (which compiles and genreates the executable) but when attempting to do the smae with CMake I am getting errors.

Here is the error:

```
Linking CXX executable discoveryService
/home/projects/OMAP- L137/timesys/SDK/omapl137_evm/toolchain/bin/../../toolchain/lib/crt1.o: In function    `_start':
(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [arm/communications/discoveryService] Error 1
make[1]: *** [arm/communications/CMakeFiles/discoveryService.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The original Makefile used three flags ***-lpthread*** ***-lc*** & ***-o*** If I am understanding correctly the ***-o*** just means to name the executable a specific name so with CMake ***ADD_EXECUTABLE*** I shouldn't need that since we specify the name of the executable there. I have included my 2 CMakeLists and the original Makefile for reference and any help is greatly appreciated since this has stumped me for the second day now..

Top Level CMakeList

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(633)
#this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
#this one not so much
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
SET(FACTORY_CURRENT /home/projects/OMAP-L137/timesys/factory-current)
SET(DSPLINK_PATH ${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-    1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01)
SET(DSPLINK_PACKAGE_DIR ${FACTORY_CURRENT}/${DSPLINK_PATH})
SET(TOOLCHAIN_LOC ${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-   uclibcgnueabi/toolchain/bin)

#read file into variable 'defines'
file(READ ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/dsplink_config/dsplink_defines.txt defines) 
#turn space separation into CMake list
string(REPLACE " " ";" defines "${defines}") 
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${defines})

# specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_LOC}/armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++ "-lpthread -lc")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_LOC}/armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++ "lpthread -lc")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -c ")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS})

#specify the linker
SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "/OMAP-L137/timesys/SDK/omapl137_evm/toolchain/bin/armv5l- timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++ -lpthread -lc")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "/OMAP-L137/timesys/SDK/omapl137_evm/toolchain/bin/armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++ -lpthread -lc")
SET(CMAKE_LINKER "/OMAP-L137/timesys/SDK/omapl137_evm/toolchain/bin/armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++ -lpthread -lc")

# where is the target environment 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/projects/OMAP-L137/timesys/factory-current)
SET(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR /home/chrisk/633/)

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
#SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin)
SET(RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(arm)
```

Second Level CMakeList:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/framework      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/flagDictionary
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/logging ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dsp/include   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/modbus ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/expat)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux- uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/usr)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/home/projects/OMAP-L137/timesys/factory-20120925-633/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/usr)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/home/projects/OMAP-L137/timesys/factory-20120925-633/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/sys/Linux)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/usr)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/sys/Linux)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/sys/Linux/2.6.18)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/src/samples/loop)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/src/samples/loop/Linux)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/src/samples/loop/Linux/2.6.18)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/BUILD/INCLUDE/USER)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink- 1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/export/INCLUDE/Linux/OMAPL1XX/internal)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_DIR}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/toolchain/include)

SET(communications_SOURCES 
discoveryService.cpp
httpService.cpp
modbusRTUService.cpp
modbusService.cpp
streamingService.cpp
trendMap.cpp
trendService.cpp
tripBuffer.cpp
tripReader.cpp
)

ADD_LIBRARY(communications ${communications_SOURCES})
SET(SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(libcommunications.a PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-lpthread -lc"  ))
SET(SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(libcommunications.a PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX))

LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/flagDictionary  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/framework ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/communications 
${DSPLINK_PACKAGE_DIR}/dsplink/gpp/export/BIN/Linux/OMAPL1XX/RELEASE/ "-lpthread -lc")

ADD_EXECUTABLE(discoveryService discoveryService.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(discoveryService flagDictionary framework communications dsplink.lib)
```

Original Makefile:

```
$(shell ../../build_environment.sh)

BIN = ../../build/bin
TMP = build

BUILD_DEF = -DBUILD=$(BUILD_VERSION) -DBUILD_DATE=$(BUILD_DATE)

# these files are captured from the DSPLink Sample build directory (and the named  changed)
# they contain the appropriate includes and flags to build a dsplink application.
DSPLINK_INCLUDES = $(shell cat ../dsplink_config/dsplink_includes.txt)
DSPLINK_FLAGS = $(shell cat ../dsplink_config/dsplink_flags.txt)
DSPLINK_DEFINES = $(shell cat ../dsplink_config/dsplink_defines.txt)
DSPLINK_LIBS =     $(DSPLINK_PACKAGE_DIR)/dsplink/gpp/export/BIN/Linux/OMAPL1XX/RELEASE/dsplink.lib


#Our project variables
INCLUDE= -I. -I../framework -I../flagDictionary -I../logging -I../../dsp/include - I../modbus -I../expat

TOOLCHAIN = /OMAP-L137/timesys/SDK/omapl137_evm/toolchain/bin
#TOOLCHAIN = ${FACTORY_DIR}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/toolchain/bin
PLATFORM=armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi

#Compile Options
CC=$(TOOLCHAIN)/$(PLATFORM)-g++
LINKER=$(TOOLCHAIN)/$(PLATFORM)-g++
CFLAGS+=$(BUILD_DEF) $(INCLUDE)
DEBUG =  

#list of things to compile.
FW_BUILD_DIR=../framework/build
LOG_BUILD_DIR=../logging/build
XML_BUILD_DIR=../expat/build
MODBUS_BUILD_DIR=../modbus/build
FLAG_DICT_BUILD_DIR=../flagDictionary/build

CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS= $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/application.o \
                $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/arguments.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/com.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/memoryManagerBase.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/memoryManager.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/lockManager.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/stopWatch.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/controlCom.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/status.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/paths.o \
        $(LOG_BUILD_DIR)/subsystemLogMasks.o \
        $(LOG_BUILD_DIR)/logger.o

# removed utils.o from CORE

NET_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS=  $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/message.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/chunk.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/multicastSocket.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/serverSocket.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/socket.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/tcpReader.o

CONF_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS= $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/configuration.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/editConfig.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/parseConfig.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/xpath.o \
        $(XML_BUILD_DIR)/xmlparse.o \
        $(XML_BUILD_DIR)/xmlrole.o \
        $(XML_BUILD_DIR)/xmltok.o

MODBUS_OBJECTS=     $(MODBUS_BUILD_DIR)/modbus.o \
        $(MODBUS_BUILD_DIR)/modbusFacade.o

MODBUS_RTU_OBJECTS= $(MODBUS_BUILD_DIR)/modbus.o \
        $(MODBUS_BUILD_DIR)/rtuFacade.o

FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS=  $(FLAG_DICT_BUILD_DIR)/flagEntry.o \
        $(FLAG_DICT_BUILD_DIR)/flagDictionary.o

OBJECTS = discoveryService.o \
  httpService.o \
  modbusService.o \
  streamingService.o \
  trendMap.o \
  trendService.o \
  tripBuffer.o \
  modbusRTUService.o \
  tripReader.o
EXES = discoveryService httpService modbusService streamingService trendService  tripReader modbusRTUService cmprXfr

all: $(OBJECTS) $(EXES)

.c.o:
mkdir -p build
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DSPLINK_INCLUDES) $(DSPLINK_FLAGS) $(DSPLINK_DEFINES) $(DEBUG)   -o $(TMP)/$@ $< 

.cpp.o:e
mkdir -p build
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DSPLINK_INCLUDES) $(DSPLINK_FLAGS) $(DSPLINK_DEFINES) $(DEBUG)  -o $(TMP)/$@ $< 

discoveryService: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) discoveryService.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/discoveryService.o     $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS) $(CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(NET_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(CONF_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)
```

Again, any and all help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A general hint: instead of the global functions (`add_definitions`) I really recommend `target_compile_definitions`. You can pass linker options through `target_link_libraries`. That way dependencies are correctly propagated when using the created library with `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Also, pulling out the toolchain stuff into a separate toolchain file would make it much easier to reuse it for other projects. Have a look at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#The_toolchain_file (although, judging from the comments in your top level cmake file, it seems as if you already have)

Comment: The toolchain is in a separate location. How exactly would I pass linker options using TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES?